# Ошибка “PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in…”

Tags: php

Перебираю массив на совпадения, те которые совпадают - удаляю.

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($arrPhotoName); $i++){
    for($j = $i+1; $j < count($arrPhotoName); $j++){
        if($arrPhotoName[$i] === $arrPhotoName[$j]){
            unset($arrPhotoName[$j]);  
        }
    }
} ?>
```

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\www\apache\Apache24\htdocs\electroperedachi\adminka_photo.php on line 200
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in D:\www\apache\Apache24\htdocs\electroperedachi\adminka_photo.php on line 200

И так много раз. Не могу понять в чем причина, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя обращаться к методам просто по индексу, когда вы их удаляете.

```
 <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($arrPhotoName); $i++){
       for($j = $i+1; $j < count($arrPhotoName); $j++){
            if(isset($arrPhotoName[$i], $arrPhotoName[$j])){
                  if($arrPhotoName[$i] === $arrPhotoName[$j]){
                         unset($arrPhotoName[$j]);  
                  }
            }
       }
    } ?>
```

Судя по алгоритму, вы просто удаляете повторы.

Попробуйте: array_unique()

Answer (score 0):

```
Notice: Undefined offset:
```

Значит, что нет такого значения в массиве, с таким ключем

Comment: Английский я знаю, спасибо) А как проблему решить то?

Comment: проследить, где же именно вы в ключ пихаете невпихуемое

Comment: согласен с комментом выше, array_unique вам в помощь